# jira macro to represent jira report in hierarchal (in terms of epic,story,taks,sub-task) way

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-plugin

My team is following below hierarchal.

epic -> story -> task -> subtask

I need to show report in tabular form as follow

```
epic1
 story1
  task1
   subtask1
  task2
   subtask2
```

Can somebody help me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Structure](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/34717/structure-project-management-at-scale) add-on for Jira. It is possible to embed it into a confluence page.

Comment: Thanks @amuratova. This is what i was expected. but it is not free. Any free one equivalent to Structure?